# How do you add with variables in python

Tags: python

I tried this:

```py
a = input()
print("+")
b = input()
c =a+b
print(c)
```

But it output 55 instead of 10 when I input 5 + 5

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Codes are text, so post them as text. See the **Code Blocks** section of the [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: It would be better if you wrote the code directly into the question rather than link to an image of it. Makes it easier for future viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are concatenating strings instead of adding integers, you can use `int()` to convert from string to integer and `str()` to convert from integer to string.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `print(5+5)` you will get `10`.
If you run `print('5'+'5')` you will get `55` because the `+` operator will concatenate strings together.